# Using Styled Components in functional React components

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

*(I hope and assume that there is a simple answer to this question, but I could not find it in the docs)*

I've just converted a React project to use Styled Components, and love the DRYness and reusability. But, I've not yet figured out the syntax for using styled components in existing functional components that do other work too.

Here's one example:

```
const StyledSearchBarPane = styled(Pane)`
    grid-area: search-bar;
`;

const SearchBarPane = () => {
  const {query} = useContext(panelContext);
  let [newQuery, setNewQuery] = useState(query);
  return (
    <StyledSearchBarPane>
      <Bar>
        <SearchInput newQuery={newQuery} setNewQuery={setNewQuery}/>
      </Bar>
    </StyledSearchBarPane>
  );
};
```

How can I avoid naming `StyledSearchBarPane`? It's only used once -- in `SearchBarPane` -- and I'd rather it were simply part of the latter's definition.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can.

Basically what you need to do is use your component as you would normally do and if you want to use a local style on the component without creating one you can use a Wrapper like you did.

But the change is, instead of exporting your component you export the wrapper. Then your component will receive as props ***className*** and you need to put it where you want to apply thoses style, in the example since it's globally you put in the root element.

If you don't put the className props it won't style anything.

```
const SearchBarPane = ({className}) => {
  const {query} = useContext(panelContext);
  let [newQuery, setNewQuery] = useState(query);
  return (
    <div className={className}>
      <Bar>
        <SearchInput newQuery={newQuery} setNewQuery={setNewQuery}/>
      </Bar>
    </div>
  );
};

const StyledSearchBarPane = styled(SearchBarPane)`
    grid-area: search-bar;
`;


export default StyledSearchBarPane;
```

https://styled-components.com/docs/advanced

Comment: Maybe my question wasn't clear enough?
I don't want to export StyledSearchBarPane.  It's not used anywhere but here.
I want exactly the opposite: I don't want to name it explicitly. Rather, I want to use its styled component syntax directly in the definition of SearchBarPane.

Comment: Do you use somehwere your component SearchBarPane ? when you export StyledSearchBarPane you're exporting SearchbarPane. You only apply style on your component without putting StyledSearchBarPane in your html, you just have to use className props

Comment: Either I'm not understanding your answer, or you are not understanding my question.  Can you explain more clearly, or give an example?

Remember, I don't need to export anything. Exporting is not relevant to this question.  You can imagine that my entire application is very small and in one file. 

My question is how to inline the contents of StyledSearchBarPane into SearchBarPane's definition.  I'm hoping that it is simply a matter of my not having found the right syntax in the docs.